# LARAVEL - How to see if an application for user already exists

Tags: php, laravel

For a job board application, trying to see if an application is already present for the job post for the user so the apply button isn't displayed any longer. This is my code currently. I'm guessing I may have to pass in the $job->id somewhere? Any idea how to check this? Thanks!

```
@if ((auth()->user()->applications()->job()->count() >= 1))
   <a class="btn-full btn-block text-center mt-2" type="button">YOU HAVE ALREADY APPLIED</a>
@else
   <a class="btn-full btn-block text-center mt-2" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#applicationModal">APPLY NOW</a>
@endif
```

Comment: Please share more details. That does not look like valid PHP code to me

Comment: @PinkShark Your suspicion seems correct; if you have the ID of the job, then you need to pass it to your query, something along the lines of `auth()->user()->applications()->job()->where('id', $job->id)->exists()` should work, I would think. Also @NicoHaase This is PHP, but in `.blade` template format `{{ php code goes here }}`, or `@if( php code ...) @else ... @endif`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, found the solution with that in mind:

```
@if ($job->applications()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->exists())
```